The following system error occurred: A device attached to the system is not functioning. While creating OLab cube
The following system error occurred:  A device attached to the system is not functioning. This erorr appears while i wanna create a olab-cube.

I have already try to change locale and localName as it recomendeed in many advice.I change it for mssqlserver and for mssqlserverolapService and then restart them
But it dosnt work.I dont know what i shoud do.So ready to try any advice
